# Program that asks for numbers until a letter is input in C

Tags: c

Hi so im trying to make a program that asks for numbers until a letter is typed in C.This is what I have

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
    long siz = 10;
    float *biglist = malloc(sizeof(float)* siz);
    int n, sum = 0;
    while ((n  = getchar() )!= "d"){
        scanf("%d",n);
        sum = sum + n;
    }
    printf("The sum is : %d",sum);
}
```

Comment: `"x"` is a string literal, not a character literal like `'x'`. `while ((chr  = getchar() )!= "x"){` eats one character from the beginning of every input. Why are you allocating an array of `float` to hold integers?

Comment: Do you want to save floating points or integers into your array?

Comment: You should always check the return value of `scanf`. On the other hand, you may want to use `fgets` instead of `scanf`. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: If you want to use `scanf`, with `%d` or `%f`, and if you check its return value, it will return 0 the first time you type "x" (or anything other than a number, for that matter).

Comment: But please notice that what you have can't work.  If you call `getchar`, to read one character, to see if it's an 'x', then if it isn't, it was probably the first digit of one of your numbers, and you'll have lost it.

Comment: What should happen if the input is "Y"? I.e. neither number nor "X".

Comment: This call: `scanf("%d",chr)` is wrong two different ways.  (1) You need an `&`.  (2) `%d` is for ints, but `chr` is a float.

Comment: Did you notice you're not using the `ma` array for anything?

Comment: See [man 3 getchar()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html)  (better)

Comment: Moti, Save time, enable all warnings.

Answer (score 1):

While you can do *character-oriented* input with `getchar()` and look for some special character to break the loop, that probably isn't the best way to go. Instead when you are reading user-input, you want to use *line-oriented* input functions to ensure you consume a complete line of input at a time. This ensures there are no offending characters left unread in `stdin` that will mess up your next input. Now while that is mitigated by reading a character at a time -- the logic you will need to employ to handle all tests and conversions reinvents the wheel.

Instead, if you read a line at a time, you can allow the user to enter as many numbers as they like (one-per-line, up to the limit of your allocation) and then simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone on an empty line to stop input. The standard approach is to read a line of input into a buffer (character array) and then parse the needed information from the buffer using `sscanf()` or if more error detection and reporting is warranted, using `strtol()`, `strtof()`, `strtod()`, etc..

When reading a line at a time, simply provide a sufficiently sized buffer to handle the longest anticipated line (and the cat stepping on the keyboard). If you are on an embedded device, just reduce the buffer size accordingly. To size the buffer (or anything else needing a fixed size), `#define` a constant or use a global `enum` for the same purpose, e.g.

```
#define MAXF 1000       /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 1024
....
    char line[MAXC] = "";
    float *ma = malloc (MAXF * sizeof *ma),     /* or float ma[MAXF] = {0}; */
```

Now you simply read input checking that the number of inputs fit in your array and checking that `'\n'` alone wasn't entered, e.g.

```
    puts ("enter one float per-line, [Enter] alone when done");
    
    /* while ma not full, and line read and not empty line */
    while (nfloat < MAXF && fgets (line, MAXC, stdin) && *line != '\n') {
```

For converting the input to `float`, simply use `sscanf()` to parse a `float` from the buffer `line` ***validating*** that a successful conversion took place before incrementing your `sum` and counter, e.g.

```
        /* if valid conversion to float */
        if (sscanf (line, "%f", &ma[nfloat]) == 1) {
            sum += ma[nfloat];                  /* sum float */
            nfloat += 1;                        /* increment counter */
        }
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXF 1000       /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 1024

int main (void) {
    
    char line[MAXC] = "";
    float *ma = malloc (MAXF * sizeof *ma),     /* or float ma[MAXF] = {0}; */
        sum = 0;
    size_t nfloat = 0;
    
    if (ma == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-ma");
        return 1;
    }
    
    puts ("enter one float per-line, [Enter] alone when done");
    
    /* while ma not full, and line read and not empty line */
    while (nfloat < MAXF && fgets (line, MAXC, stdin) && *line != '\n') {
        /* if valid conversion to float */
        if (sscanf (line, "%f", &ma[nfloat]) == 1) {
            sum += ma[nfloat];                  /* sum float */
            nfloat += 1;                        /* increment counter */
        }
    }
    
    printf ("The sum is : %f\n", sum);
    free (ma);      /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

(**note:** the memory allocated is freed. While this will happen automatically on program exit, you won't always allocate in `main()`. Failure to free the memory you allocate in that case will lead to a *memory-leak* if the ability to free the memory is lost)

**Example Use/Output**

```
./bin/sumfloats
enter one float per-line, [Enter] alone when done
10.1
10.3
10.3
10.3

The sum is : 41.000000
```

If you want to output all stored floats, then simply add an output loop before you output the sum, e.g.

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nfloat; i++)
        printf (i ? " %.1f" : "%.1f", ma[i]);
    
    printf ("\nThe sum is : %.2f\n", sum);
    free (ma);      /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

In that case, you would output each `float` that is part of `sum` with precision to 1 digit and the sum with a precision of 2, e.g.

```
./bin/sumfloats
enter one float per-line, [Enter] alone when done
10.1
10.3
10.3
10.3

10.1 10.3 10.3 10.3
The sum is : 41.00
```

This is a slight variation on what you were attempting, but this approach will save you a lot of grief (and potential logic errors). Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getchar()` call won't function as you imagine it would.

To begin with, `"x"` is a string literal, what you actually wanted is, `'x'`, a single character.

Your `malloc()` call is correct but you never seem to use the allocated memory and you never call `free()`.

Checking the return value of `scanf()` would be an easy to exit if anything but a floating point is entered. You can also use `fgets()` with `sscanf()`, since `scanf()` is prone to arithmetic overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t tam = 1000;
    float *ma = malloc(sizeof(float) * tam);
    float chr, sum = 0;

    if (ma == NULL) /* check that malloc succeded */
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((scanf("%f", &chr) == 1) && i < tam) /* check for overflow and scanf return value */
    {
        sum = sum + chr;
        ma[i++] = chr;
    }

    /* if you are planning on receiving input again you have to reset/clear the input buffer */

    printf("The sum is : %.1f", sum);

    free(ma);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** If you want to resize the array, you need to use `realloc()`,

```
 while ((scanf("%f", &chr) == 1)) /* check scanf return value */
    {
        if (i >= tam)
        {
            float *tmp = realloc(ma, (tam + 100) * sizeof(float)); /* resize by 100 or desired size, dont forget to add the previous size */
            if (tmp == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"Re - Allocation failed\n");
                free(ma);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
           ma = tmp;
           tam += 100; /* increase the new size */
        }

        sum = sum + chr;
        ma[i++] = chr;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have another question what can I do if my array is about to fill and I want to expand it before it does?

Comment: alex01011, Why mix types, `int, unsigned long` with `i >= tam`?  Consider a common type like `size_t` for array indexing and sizing.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Indeed, I've updated.